# Make ruby gem executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, executable

I have built a ruby gem but I need to make it executable so it could be run from the terminal. I have googled and found that I need to make a file inside the `bin/` directory, require my library and then call whatever I need from it. Also I tried `chmod +x bin/myfile` to make it executable but nothing worked.Basically, I have followed this [link](http://willschenk.com/making-a-command-line-utility-with-gems-and-thor/) but nothing worked.

In the bin directory, I have already a `console` and `setup` along with my newly created file which is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "sys_libs"
s = SysLibs
```

Here's the `.gemspec` file:

```
spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject do |f|
    f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  end
spec.bindir        = "exe"
spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| f[3..-1] }
spec.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

Anytime I try to change the executable, I get stuck with failed build. Any idea what else am I missing so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spec.bindir = "exe"` attribute should be `spec.bindir = 'bin'`.

```
spec.bindir        = 'bin'
spec.executables   = ['myfile']
```

[`bindir` is optional](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#bindir) if you place your executables in a `bin` subdirectory, because it is set by default in [rubygems/specifications.rb](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/ed1564e0db30ab8c586d2869b58ddf900a5be1ea/lib/rubygems/specification.rb#L133)
 and is [prepended to each executable](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/ed1564e0db30ab8c586d2869b58ddf900a5be1ea/lib/rubygems/specification.rb#L1529) in the list of executables.

Comment: @omarsafwany I have revised my answer to include a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on the same issue and for me the culprit was how files for inclusion into the gem were defined (which is the standard boilerplate generated by bundler):

```
spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject do |f|
  f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
end
```

What this does: Only `files` are included which have been added to `git` (retrieved in the script by `git ls-files`) are used for inclusion into the gem.

So the following then will just return an empty array:

```
spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| f[3..-1] }
```

Once, I added the executable script to git, everything worked.